# AWS boto3 Config Service list of EC2s with states

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, service, config, boto3

I would like to use Boto3 to generate a list of EC2s along with state changes (pending, running, shutting-down, terminated etc.) between a set of two date times. My understanding is that Config Service maintains histories of EC2s even if the EC2 no longer exists. I have taken a look at [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/config.html) document, however I am having difficulty understanding which functions to use in order to accomplish the task at hand.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that you have already configured *AWS Config rules* to track ec2-instance state, this approach will suit your need.

1) Get the list of ec2-instances using the [*list_discovered_resources*](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.list_discovered_resources) API.Ensure *includeDeletedResources* is set to *`True`* if you want to include deleted resources in the response.

```
response = client.list_discovered_resources(
    resourceType='AWS::EC2::Instance',
    limit=100,
    includeDeletedResources=True,
    nextToken='string'
)
```

Parse the response and store the *`resource-id`*.

2) Pass each *`resource_id`* to the  [*get_resource_config_history*](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.get_resource_config_history) API.

```
response = client.get_resource_config_history(
    resourceType='AWS::EC2::Instance',
    resourceId='i-0123af12345be162h5',      // Enter your EC2 instance id here
    laterTime=datetime(2018, 1, 7),         // Enter end date. default is current date.
    earlierTime=datetime(2018, 1, 1),       // Enter start date
    chronologicalOrder='Reverse'|'Forward',
    limit=100,
    nextToken='string'
)
```

You can parse the response and get the state changes, which ec2 instance went through for that corresponding time period.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. Do you have any simple instructions about how to track ec2-instance state in AWS Config? It does not appear to be obvious how to accomplish this.

Comment: When I run the code my outputs are aggregated counts... I would like to see resource ids of EC2s. How do I get the resource IDs of the EC2s displayed?

Comment: When you call `list_discovered_resources` API, in the response look for `resourceIdentifiers` Tag which is a list. This in-turn will have attributes like *resourceName*, *resourceId*, *resourceType* and *resourceDeletionTime*. You can loop through the response and get the resourceId's.

Comment: It is not aggregating. I made a mistake with that part of the last comment. My apologies.

Comment: Not able to comprehend fully without seeing your code. If you are trying to aggregate the state of each ec2 instance, I think you need to handle the it from your own custom python logic. I just mentioned which API's you can use to achieve your objective.

Comment: The code you supplied works for what I need. Thank you @Madhukar